# powershell to restart local computer and resume script

Tags: powershell, workflow

I am trying to re-install antivirus on multiple computers which requires reboot. I have a script to uninstall the antivirus and reboot but for installation, I have to run another script. Is there anyway to ran only one script which will perform UNINSTALL+REBOOT+INSTALL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469265/running-a-powershell-script-restarting-and-then-continue-to-run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Powershell script, restarting and then continue to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469265/running-a-powershell-script-restarting-and-then-continue-to-run)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
cd HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
new-itemproperty . TheKey -propertytype String -value "Powershell.exe Powershell script"
Restart-Computer
```

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1334887-restart-a-computer-remotely-using-powershell-and-prompt-for-computer-name-and-un